# Ember.js action on checkbox with dynamic generated id

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js, handlebars.js

In an Ember.js 2.11 template I have an *each* cycle that iterate on a model. Inside it I place an input checkbox whit dynamic generated id (like "chk-"+row_model.id). This checkbox isn't associated with any model option but enable/disable (maybe with a css class) only another input text with the same style dynamic generated id (like "txt-"+row_model.id).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template:

```
{{#each model as |row|}}
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="chk-{{row.id}}" 
            onchange={{action (action "checkboxChanged" row.id) value="target.checked"}}> 
     <input disabled type="text" id="txt-{{row.id}}">
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

controller/component:

```
  actions: {
    checkboxChanged(rowId, isChecked) {
      Ember.$('#txt-' + rowId).prop('disabled', !isChecked);
    }
  }
```

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4b448ebe2b2092f725276a11dea481ea)

You could use some artificial attribute (like `_checked`) in the model as well. Or, better yet, write a component. So previous example could be rewritten using components like this:

checked-input.hbs:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange={{action (mut isChecked) value="target.checked"}}> 
<input disabled={{isDisabled}} type="text">
```

checked-input.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isDisabled: Ember.computed.not("isChecked")
});
```

using it:

```
{{#each model as |row| }}
   {{checked-input row=row}}
{{/each}}
```

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d78ef05cd435151b6b66c4d6374a9236)

Basically, avoid direct manipulation of DOM if possible.